# Classic case of `sum` returning NA because it doesn't sum NAs

Tags: r

I am trying to use `sum` in a function, but the results are `NA`, which I think may be due to integer overflow.  But the class of the numbers I am using is numeric.

The function is most simply

```
sum((columnA-columnB)^2)
```

A value from columnA is `0.1376146` and from columnB is `0.272`

Is is the different length of decimal places?  I know how to change what is displayed, but I'm not sure that will change what R uses for `sum`.

Comment: You can't get an integer overflow when summing non-integer values. You likely have missing values in your data. Use `is.na` to check, and `sum(..., is.na=TRUE)` to remove them when summing.

Comment: Thank you, @JoshuaUlrich, I used `na.rm=TRUE` and it works now.  Sorry, downvoters, I was just trying to avoid posting a question titled, "I've been stuck for an hour and have no idea what is going on."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Following Joshua Ulrich's comment, before saying that you have some overflow problem, you should answer these questions:

1. How many elements are you summing? R can handle a BIG number of entries
2. How big are the values in your vectors? Again, R can handle quite big numbers
3. Are you summing integers or floats? If you are summing floating-point numbers, you **can't** have an integer overflow (floats are not integers)
4. Do you have `NA`s in your data? If you sum anything with `NA`s present, the result will be `NA`, unless you handle it properly.

That said, some solutions:

- Use `sum(..., na.rm=T)`  to ignore `NA`s from your object (this is the simple solution)
- Sum only non `NA` entries: `sum(yourVector[!is.na(yourVector)]` (the not so simple one)
- If you are summing a column from a data frame, subset the data frame before summing: `sum(subset(yourDataFrame, !is.na(columnToSum))[columnToSum])` (this is like using a cannon to kill a mosquito)

Comment: Just to add a subtility here. If you use na.rm=T if all values are NA then the sum will be zero. If you want to return NA instead (but still ignore if they are not all NA) then use the "the not so simple one" solution with !is.na .