Trouble counting negative values in difftime type column of dataframe in R
I have a dataframe in R named trips_2023_tidy with a column named "duration", obtained by subtracting end_time from start_time of each ride as follows:
# Calculate the difference between the 'ended_at' and 'started_at' columns to obtain the trip duration
# The difference is divided by 60 to convert from seconds to minutes and rounded to 2 decimal places

trips_2023_tidy$duration <- round((trips_2023_tidy$ended_at - trips_2023_tidy$started_at)/60, 2)

Upon examining the structure of the dataframe "str(trips_2023_tidy)", the duration column structure now appears as follows:
duration : 'difftime' num 10.85 8.48 13.23 8.77 ...

I want to count how many values in this column are negative. I tried the following code, but it always returns "NA":
sum(trips_2023_tidy$duration < 0)

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Try this example to see the problem sum(c(NA, 1:3) < 0)

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24232577/680068

gorilla_ballz123, it seems unlikely that the dupe-link is not relevant here. If you can confirm that all(!is.na(trips_2023_tidy$ended_at)) (same for started_at), then please add sample data that shows no NA values yet still produces a sum of NA. Once you do that, please @-ping me and we'll work through it, reopening as needed. Thanks and good luck!
